# Alphanumeric Counter in talend to generate id

Tags: java, talend, talend-mdm

I am trying to figure out a way in talend to generate an alphanumeric counter that creates numbers in the following way: YYXXXXXXXX

Where

- YY is calendar year
- XXXXXXXX is id which is alphanumeric counter (starting sequence number 00000001 to ZZZZZZZZ every year)

Every new year, 8 character ID should be reset and start again with 00000001

Sequence should appear like

```
00000001
00000002
00000003
...
99999999

A0000001
A0000002
A0000003
...
A9999999

B0000001
B0000002
B0000003
...
B9999999

Z0000001
Z0000002
Z0000003
...
Z9999999
...

ZA000001
ZA000002
ZA000003
...
ZA999999

......
ZZZZZZZZ
```

The last number should be ZZZZZZZZ. So it would 1-9 first, then A-Z after that.

And the year the last id that we can accommodate in a year will be 20ZZZZZZZZ

How to do this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. What have you tried thus far? What are you getting stuck on? Stackoverflow is not a 'homework/write my code for me' service. You'll be more likely to get people help you, if you show to have put in some effort yourself beforehand.

Comment: That description looks like a base 36 number system. All you have to do is make a function that takes an int and return it in base 36. Then it's just a matter of concatenating year.

Comment: Can you pls suggeat with example

Answer (score 1):

Basically it converts a number(long) to a radix with base 36, pads it with preceding zeros to match the format, concats the last two digits of current year and returns the result as a String.

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime; //for getting the current year from system clock
```

```java
public static String codegen(long input) {
    String lastTwoDigitsOfYear = Integer.toString(LocalDateTime.now().getYear()).substring(2); // the "YY"
    String radixOf36Base = Long.toString(input, 36).toUpperCase();
    String radixOf36BasePadded = String.format("%8s", radixOf36Base).replace(' ', '0'); //the "XXXXXXXX"
    return lastTwoDigitsOfYear + radixOf36BasePadded; //YYXXXXXXXX
    }
```

Comment: out of memory exception. can someone help me with code